# how to play audio streaming over network through rtsp and rtp in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, rtp

For playing video on receiver side, we can use
**gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://172.16.6.210:8554/test ! decodebin ! autovideosink**

But,
how to play audio streaming on receiver side over network through rtsp and rtp in gstreamer?

Comment: What happens when you replace autovideosink with autoaudiosink?

Answer (score 1):

gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://172.16.6.210:8554/test ! decodebin ! **autoaudiosink**

Will solve it!